# Iframe is nested when I use window.location each time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this html structure:

```
<html>
<body>
This is the container of the iframe
<iframe src="/foo.html">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

(/foo.html)

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click( function() {
window.location = window.location;
});
</script>
<body>
<a href="#">link to me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click 'link to me' several times, the iframe is nested in another iframe structure (like a copy) as this (using firebug you can verify this):

```
<html>
 <body>
  This is the container of the iframe
  <iframe src="/foo.html">
<html>
 <body>
  This is the container of the iframe
  <iframe src="/foo.html">
<html>
 <body>
  This is the container of the iframe
  <iframe src="/foo.html">
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

¿What can I do to fix this?

Comment: window.location = window.location (document.location.href = document.location.href)

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` is restricted on what it can access based on the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). If your `iframe` is from the same domain AND same subdomain, then your `iframe` can use:

```
parent.document.location
parent.window.location
parent.window.document.location
parent.document.location.href
```

Or some other similar methodology for accessing the necessary data. If it is not from the same domain and subdomain, then attempting to use any of the above code will result in an error.